# Excel IF Statement - Multiple conditions in columns

Tags: excel, if-statement, boolean, logical-operators, countif

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsynr.png)

I want to run a logical test that will execute either of two pieces of code based on a boolean outcome in MS Excel.

I have attached a sample of data. I want to run a logical IF test that executes either of two other functions based on TRUE or FALSE if column A contains "February" and column B contains the word "Breakfast" - but both conditions have to be in the same row, and can appear more than once (just has to be greater than zero). This is the code I came up with:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,"February")>0,(COUNTIF(B:B,"*Breakfast*")>0)),"Run this code","Runthatcode")
```

I'm currently learning programming and Excel so my knowledge is pretty limited right now.

Many thanks.

Fraser

Comment: Please submit the formulas that aren't working so we can better understand what your needs are

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this with cell formulas or VBA? Could you post exactly what you've tried, what output it gave, and what the desired output is?

Comment: I've amended thanks - hopefully that's clearer, and no I'm not using the VBA editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `COUNTIFS` function to accomplish this.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B, "ValueA", C:C, "ValueB") > 0, Function1, Function2)
```

Comment: Thanks David, that's what I tried but I need the IF statement to return TRUE only if both ValueA and ValueB are also contained on the same line, if that makes sense?

Comment: @FraserStirling If you use `COUNTIFS` instead of `AND(COUNTIF, COUNTIF)` it will check that both conditions are matched on the same row.